# Make command line string variables

Tags: c, command-line, makefile, symbols

I want to define values to CC_FLAGS at make command line.

```
make - f makefile CC_FLAGS=-DVERSION='\"1.2.3\"'
```

Works, but what if want to define multiple values to CC_FLAGS?

```
make -f makefile CC_FLAGS='-DVERSION='\"1.2.3\"' -DVERSION_1_2_3'
```

This doesn't work. Idea is to have a string telling the software version number as well as a symbol for #ifdef usage.

Comment: Good point, but that was a typo :D

Comment: Try `echo`-ing the `CC_FLAGS` from the makefile

Comment: Consider using `-DVERSION=1.2.3` at the command line and internally `#define STR_VERSION STRINGIFY(VERSION)` and `#define STRINGIFY(x) #x`.  Then you don't have to fuss with the quotes as much.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the additional single quotes *inside* the ones you have. This works:

```
make -f makefile CC_FLAGS='-DVERSION=\"1.2.3\" -DVERSION_1_2_3'
```

as shown with this program

```
int main (void)
{
    printf ("Are we defined?\n");
#ifdef VERSION_1_2_3
    printf ("yeah we have a version.\n");
#endif

#ifdef VERSION
    printf ("version is: \"%s\"\n", VERSION);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper escaping/quoting for your shell. Try this:

```
make -f makefile CC_FLAGS='-DVERSION=\"1.2.3\" -DVERSION_1_2_3'
```